# How to get the index of the biggest number in array?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this array:

```
float[] sizeEdge = new float[12,43,556,98];
```

Maybe my question will seem naive to some of ou but, Im a newer in .NET,
I need to get the array index of the biggest number.

How do I implement it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are lots of approaches you could try. What have you tried so far, and how did it go?

Comment: I tryed this:
float maxEdgeSize = sizeEdge.Max();
than i passing threw the array with help of if() statement
to check for the biggest number.
But i'm searching for something more elegant.

Comment: there are different approach for your question, it depends on what your teacher wants you to do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IEnumerable.Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343284.aspx) method like;

> Returns the maximum value in a sequence of values.

```
float[] sizeEdge = new float[] { 12f, 43f, 556f, 98f };
int maxIndex = Array.IndexOf(sizeEdge, sizeEdge.Max());
Console.WriteLine(sizeEdge[maxIndex]);
```

Result will be;

```
556
```

Here a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/tEn3HC).

Answer (score 5):

```
float max = sizeEdge.Max();
int maxIndex = Array.IndexOf(sizeEdge, max);
```

Note this will iterate the array twice, and will throw an exception if the array is empty. If you need to handle these, a loop is probably cleaner. You could create an extension method:

```
public static int IndexOfMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if(! seq.Any()) return -1;
    T max = seq.First();
    int maxIdx = 0;
    int idx = 1;

    foreach(T item in seq.Skip(1))
    {
        if(max.CompareTo(item) < 0)
        {
            max = item;
            maxIdx = idx;
        }
        ++idx;
    }

    return maxIdx;
}
```

or a linq version:

```
public static int IndexOfMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return seq.Select((f, idx) => new { Val = f, Idx = idx })
        .Aggregate(new { Max = default(T), MaxIndex = -1 }, (mp, fp) =>
        {
            return mp.MaxIndex == -1 || fp.Val.CompareTo(mp.Max) > 0 ? new { Max = fp.Val, MaxIndex = fp.Idx } : mp;
        }).MaxIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float max = 0;
int key = 0;
for(int x=0;x<sizeEdge.Length;x++){
 if(max<sizeEdge[x]){
  max=sizeEdge;
  key=x;
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if either the array is empty (you'll have a key of 0 which is invalid) or if everything is negative.

Comment: Maybe you should change int max = 0; to float max = float.MinValue;

Answer (score 2):

```
float[] sizeEdge = new float[]{12f, 43f, 556f, 98f};
var result = Array.IndexOf(sizeEdge,sizeEdge.Max());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq.

Don't forget the using statement `using System.Linq;`

```
int indexOfMax = Array.IndexOf(sizeEdge, sizeEdge.Max());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work; generalised to `IEnumerable<float>`:

```
// Returns index of maximum value, or -1 if there are no numbers.

int IndexOfMax(IEnumerable<float> numbers)
{
    float max = 0;
    int indexOfMax = -1;
    int index = 0;

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        if ((number > max) || (indexOfMax < 0))
        {
            indexOfMax = index;
            max = number;
        }

        ++index;
    }

    return indexOfMax;
}
```

This only traverses the array once, rather than twice like what happens if you use both `.Max()` and `IndexOf()` so it should be somewhat faster.

You can generalise this to types that implement `IComparable<T>` like so:

```
// Returns index of maximum value, or -1 if there are no numbers.

int IndexOfMax<T>(IEnumerable<T> numbers) where T: IComparable<T>
{
    T max = default(T);
    int indexOfMax = -1;
    int index = 0;

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        if ((number.CompareTo(max) > 0) || (indexOfMax < 0))
        {
            indexOfMax = index;
            max = number;
        }

        ++index;
    }

    return indexOfMax;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alternative version of `select`.

```
float[] sizeEdge = new float[12,43,556,98];

var maxIndex = sizeEdge.Select((x,i) => new { value = x, index = i})
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.value)
                       .Select(x=> x.index)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```